# How to safely convert const char* to const char8_t* in C++20?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, c++20

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842261/673852) I learned that in C++17 we can open `std::fstream` using a UTF-8 path via `std::filesystem::u8path`. But in C++20 this function is deprecated, and we are supposed to pass `const char8_t*` to `std::filesystem::path` constructor instead.

Here comes the problem: although we can legally convert (via `reinterpret_cast`) any pointer to `const char*`, we can't do backwards: from `const char*` to e.g. `const char8_t*` (it would break strict aliasing rules). So if we have some external API returning a `char`-based UTF-8 representation of the filename (e.g. from a library written in C), we can't safely convert the pointer to `char8_t`-based one.

So, how are we supposed to convert such `char`-based view of UTF-8 strings to `char8_t`-based view of them?

Comment: "we can't do backwards". Why would you want to? UTF-8 string data should go in `char8_t` strings to begin with.

Comment: @n.m. should doesn't mean it does. There's any number of libraries designed before 2020 which don't even know of `char8_t`.

Comment: Old libraries may continue to use old APIs. Deprecated doesn't mean removed.

Comment: I guess we should wait until the standard is finalized and compilers implemented everything regarding `char8_t`. I'd bet the cast will be save on MSVC since, to my knowledge, it doesn't take advantage on the SAR and gcc&clang will have some switch to treat `char8_t` as `char` to allow aliasing. UB is UB but it is how it is with SAR and legacy->new code bridges.

Comment: if the `char[]` data is already encoded in UTF-8, then simply `memcpy()` or `std::copy()` it as-is into a `char8_t[]` buffer.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. UTF-8 string data cannot go in `char8_t` because currently there is no libraries which can read data into char8_t, we don't even have a `std::u8fstream`.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [P0482](http://wg21.link/p0482) proposal that introduced `char8_t` and deprecated `u8path`.

Your observations are correct; it is not permissible to use `reinterpret_cast` to produce a `char8_t` pointer to a sequence of `char` objects.  This is discussed further at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453713/11634221.

Though `std::filesystem::u8path` has been deprecated in C++20, there are no plans for its imminent removal; you can continue to use it.  Further, [P1423](http://wg21.link/p1423) corrects an unintended consequence of the changes in [P0482](http://wg21.link/p0482) and permits it to be called with ranges of both `char` and `char8_t` in C++20.  As far as I'm aware, no implementors have annotated `std::filesystem::u8path` as deprecated (I don't know if any plan to do so).

There is no (well-formed) way to produce a `char8_t` pointer based view of a sequence of `char`.  It is possible to write a range/iterator adapter that, internally, converts the individual `char` values to `char8_t` on iterator dereference.  Such an adapter could satisfy the requirements of the C++17 and C++20 random access iterator requirements for a non-mutable iterator (it can't satisfy requirements for a mutable iterator because the dereference operation wouldn't be able to provide an lvalue, nor could it satisfy requirements for a contiguous iterator).  Such an adapter would suffice for calls to the `std::filesystem::path` constructors that accept ranges.  Hmm, this might be a useful enough adapter to add to https://github.com/tahonermann/char8_t-remediation.

An alternative to a view over the underlying `char` data is, of course, to copy it, but I can appreciate why doing so might be considered undesirable (we already tend to do a lot of copying when working with `std::filesystem::path`).

Comment: `std::u8string_view` SHOULD have been this adapter. It is immutable and its original intent was insulating users from caring about the underlying string storage. Why can't we have nice things :( ?

Comment: Making `std::u8string_view` that adapter would have required use of `reinterpret_cast` (or similar) within its implementation.  That would have prevented `std::u8string_view` from being `constexpr`.  Additionally, even if we adopted some kind of compiler magic to make that work, it would have been an odd one-off unless we also extended that magic to `std::span` and other future types like `std::text_view`.

Answer (score 2):

From [this character types reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types) about `char8_t`:

> It has the same size, signedness, and alignment as `unsigned char` (and. therefore, the same size and alignment as `char` and `signed char`), but is a distinct type.

Because it's a *distinct type* you can not convert from `const char*` to `const char8_t*` without breaking strict aliasing. But for all practical purposes, since `char8_t` is basically a `unsigned char` you can use `reinterpret_cast` to convert the pointer. It's wrong but will work.

For proper correctness either use `char8_t` to begin with, or copy the original characters into a `char8_t` buffer (or `std::u8string`).

Comment: Size, signedness and alignment is not what lets us defy strict aliasing rules.

Comment: Since it is a distinct type you can't access the cast pointer because it violates the strict aliasing rule.