# Why doesn't basic_regex support char8_t?

Tags: c++, regex, c++20

As the title says, the following code snippet generates C2027:

```cpp
#include<regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    basic_regex<char8_t> r;
    return 0;
}
```

And the error msg was:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::regex_traits<char8_t>'
message : see declaration of 'std::regex_traits<char8_t>'
message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_regex<char8_t,std::regex_traits<char8_t>>' being compiled
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'locale_type'
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::regex_traits<char8_t>'
message : see declaration of 'std::regex_traits<char8_t>'
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'string_type'
error C3646: 'imbue': unknown override specifier
error C2059: syntax error: '('
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
error C3646: 'getloc': unknown override specifier
error C2059: syntax error: '('
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
error C2079: 'std::basic_regex<char8_t,std::regex_traits<char8_t>>::_Traits' uses undefined class 'std::regex_traits<char8_t>'
```

But `basic_regex<char>` works

Can someone tell me why?

char and char8_t look like the same type in terms of their usage...

I'm using VS2021

Comment: `char` and `char8_t` may "look like" the same type to you, but to the compiler they're not. The same signedness and size does not guarantee that 2 integral types are the same...

Comment: @fabian So they are distinct types, But why I can‘t even instantiate basic_regex<char8_t>

Comment: You might want to look at the answers to this questions [Is C++20 'char8_t' the same as our old 'char'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402464/is-c20-char8-t-the-same-as-our-old-char). This explains why those are not the same.

Comment: `But why I can‘t even instantiate basic_regex<char8_t>`, because the specialization of `std::regex_traits` for `char8_t` is not implemented (maybe also other specializations for `char8_t` are missing too)

Comment: @t.niese oh thx, maybe I should use a wrapper class between regex and u8string

Comment: @Suric why? Just implement these traits.

Comment: @t.niese It's allowed to specialize `std::regex_traits` (as well as most other templates in `std`). But the specialization must be on a user-defined type, i.e. not on `chat8_t`.

Comment: At least your compiler told you. gcc just throws an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char8_t` support in the C++ standard is rudimentary. There were some minor changes to locales related to `char8_t` but they were [broken](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3767). Since `std::regex` depends on the locale, it cannot support `char8_t` either.

Putting aside other deficiencies of `std::regex`, you don't really need `char8_t` to use it with UTF-8. On most platforms normal `char` strings are already UTF-8 and on Windows with MSVC you can compile with `/utf-8` which will give you portable Unicode support on major operating systems.