# Unable to convert std::string into std::basic_string<char8_t>, why?

Tags: c++, string, casting, c++20, codecvt

I am facing the following problem, I am trying to convert an `std::string` object into an `std::basic_string<char8_t>` one, using the `codecvt` library. The code is the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

int main()
 {
  std::string str = "Test string";
  std::wstring_convert <std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 <char8_t>, char8_t> converter_8_t;
  converter_8_t.from_bytes( str );
 }
```

The problem is that when I try to compile it with `g++ -std=c++20` (`g++ 11.2.0`) I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cck8g9Wa.o: in function `std::__cxx11::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char8_t, 1114111ul, (std::codecvt_mode)0>, char8_t, std::allocator<char8_t>, std::allocator<char> >::wstring_convert()':
other.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1115wstring_convertISt18codecvt_utf8_utf16IDuLm1114111ELSt12codecvt_mode0EEDuSaIDuESaIcEEC2Ev[_ZNSt7__cxx1115wstring_convertISt18codecvt_utf8_utf16IDuLm1114111ELSt12codecvt_mode0EEDuSaIDuESaIcEEC5Ev]+0x2c): undefined reference to `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char8_t, 1114111ul, (std::codecvt_mode)0>::codecvt_utf8_utf16(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do you know what could be the problem? Am I trying to convert the `std::string` object in the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: *Do you know what could be the problem?* -- That is a linker error, not a compiler error.  Your code compiled just fine -- it probably has something to do with the libraries you are linking to. Unfortunately I do not know g++ suite well enough to tell you the issue with the libraries you are using.

Comment: Why are you using `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 `? Where is UTF-16 involved at all? For that matter, why do you think you need to transcode into UTF-8? What encoding is the original string in if not already UTF-8? *Such* an XY problem..! It seems to me you just need to call `std::u8string`'s iterator-pair constructor from the original string's `begin`/`end`, but as it's not clear what this is supposed to accomplish, who can really say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[C++ keywords: char8_t (since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/char8_t)

As far as I understand char8_t is of char type as is your std::string. A simple cast should work.

Comment: The OP's code compiled as-is with no issues, so no cast should be necessary.  Not saying you are wrong, but the compiler *should* have issued some sort of diagnostic if a cast was really necessary.

Comment: Again as far as I understand OP is using a wide string converter and the type used is narrow.

Comment: *"A simple cast should work."* -- could you be more specific? A cast of what to what? I would consider `static_cast<void*>(&str)` to be a simple cast, but I don't see it making the question's code work. *One approach: could you add a line of code to illustrate what you described in text?*

Comment: &JaMit "_could you be more specific?_" - No, again as far as I understand I wouldn't. [Is C++20 'char8_t' the same as our old 'char'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402464/is-c20-char8-t-the-same-as-our-old-char/57453713#57453713)